# Can I highlight date based on whether today is past a certain (rolling) bi-annual date?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am trying to use Excel to keep track of routine updates we run twice a year in Jan and July for employees. I want to highlight the cell using conditional formatting if TODAY is past the next required check.

However, there is a caveat - an update might be run between these dates for non-routine reasons, but still needs to be redone next Jan/Jul, so I can't simply ask if today is X number of days/months after the last update.

For example:

> **Name**...................**Last Update**
>   John Doe.............1/8/2019
>   Jane Doe.............3/7/2019
>   John Smith...........7/12/2019
>   Jane Smith...........11/28/2019

Assuming TODAY is *any* time after 7/1/19, I need to highlight the cells containing the dates 1/8/2019 and 3/7/2019 but **not** 7/12/2019 or 11/28/2019.

When TODAY rolls over from 12/31/19 to 1/1/20, I need 7/12/2019 and 11/28/2019 to now also be highlighted.

I've tried searching for an answer, but I can't find anything based on a difference in date range, rather than specific date. I can't decide if I'm missing something obvious or not.

Is this possible? Does this even make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your **Last Update** dates are in range `I2:I7`, enter the following formula as the **Formatting Rule**:

```
=TODAY()>(EOMONTH($I2,-MONTH($I2)+IF(MONTH($I2)>=7,12,6))+1)
```

Replace `$I2` with the starting cell of your **Last Update** date range.

The logic is to use **EOMONTH** function to find out the Cut-off Date for each **Last Update** date, and then compare it with **TODAY()**. Please see Column J and K of my solution for clarification.

There is no need to create any helper columns as long as you put the above formula as the formatting rule for relevant range of data, which is `I2:I7` in my solution.

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula to in your conditional formatting:

```
=AND(B1<DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),IF(MONTH(TODAY())>=6,6,1),1),B1<>"")
```

[image]

Comment: It will now.  @JvdV missed that after january 1st it would pass `0` for the month and we want 1.

Comment: @JvdV got too fancy, simple if better