# Highlight empty cell based on multiple date comparison

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I would like to highlight the cells based on multiple dates comparison.
There are 4 dates (D1, D2, D3, D4) on the left for different projects. which need to be compared with each month first date(M1, M2, M3... M12).

so, I need to check if the cells below M1 (empty cells) falls between D1, D2 then fill red, if falls between D2,D3 fill yellow and if falls between D3,D4 then fill green. This has to be done for each cell which is below M2, M3.. M12. Each project has different time line, so I need to check for each project based on D1,D2,D3,D4 and M1,M2...mx.

I tried using the conditional formatting and used "Use a formulate to determine which cells to format" for one cell below M1 for first project. then stretched by mouse over from left to right. It did not reflect any colour in any cell.

please suggest how can i do it.

Thanks
Sbx.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/57794266/4961700

Comment: And this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71880218/4961700 should be able to work it from there especially the second one.

Comment: Thanks Mike. It seems the following formulate is bit complex to understand. =AND(B1<DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),IF(MONTH(TODAY())>=6,6,1),1),B1<>"")
I got the YEAR and MONTH calculation based on TODAY(), but what is >=6,6,1 means ?  also what is the meaning of B1<>"" ? Could you help on these two queries ?

Comment: Break it into bits to work out what is going on. Example: B1>C1, B1>=C1, B1<C1, B1<=C1, B1=C1, B1<>C1 : <> is “not equal to”